# Do a less on file returned by which command

Tags: shell

I have a file which is in one of the folders in the $PATH. I want to see the contents of it using less. Problem is I seem to need to run which command to find the actual location and then do less on it.

```
e.g.
> which students.csv
/opt/files/students.csv
> less /opt/files/students.csv
```

Is there a way to combine these two commands and do less on the ouput of which command? Thanks.

Comment: `less "$(which students.csv)"`

Answer (score 3):

You can run

```
less `which students.csv`
```

Recent shells also allow

```
less $(which students.csv)
```

Comment: Works in bash(didn't in tcsh, not a problem), thank you! What is the name of this feature if you don't mind?

Comment: @Nemo, 'Command Substitution`

Comment: @Nemo which is a tcsh builtin; try less \`/usr/bin/which students.csv\`